# My code didn't work correctly with if ||

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is my code

```
<?php

if( $country==("United Stats" || Canada || United Kingdom) ) {
   echo $Country;
}

?>
```

I want to say "if Country == United Stats 'or' Canada 'or' United Kingdom >>>
 echo $Country

When i use || it not work correctly
What is the wrong please ?

Comment: Because that's not how `||` works.  You need `if ($country == "United Stats" || $country == "Canada" || $country == "United Kingdom")`.

Comment: where in the manual does it say that will work? - hint it doesn't

Comment: Ignore all the answers below so far, and use `in_array($country, array("United States","Canada","UnitedKingdom"))`

Comment: with 3 or more im inclined towards if (in_array($country,array("United Stats","Canada","United Kingdom")) ...

Comment: @Dagon great minds think alike, no?

Comment: I want to visit the United *Stats*, i'm sure if more fair than the United *States*

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, you need to write:

```
if( $country=="United Stats" || $country=="Canada" || $country=="United Kingdom" ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$cs = array('United States', 'Canada', 'United Kingdom');
if(in_array($country, $cs)){
echo $country
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (in_array($country, array('United Stats', 'Canada', 'United Kingdom'))) {
```

Comment: @Michael thank you.  I think this is most like what the OP was going for (plus everyone had already gone with the more obvious answers and I wanted a different answer.  I added this before AMayer, who has two upvotes for the same method for some reason).  Always hate it when you're downvoted and you don't know why :(

Comment: I hate it when people post my comment as an answer, but I'll give you an up-vote anyway :-)

Comment: @Dagon thanks.  I guess you did post your comment before I answered.  I hadn't read it, though (hand to God).

Comment: well as God is a figment of collective delusion .. But I believe you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

you have to compare $country to each variable

```
if ($country == "United States" ||
    $country == "Canada" ||
    $country == "United Kingdom") {

    echo $country;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if( $country=="United Stats" Or $country=="Canada" Or $country=="United Kingdom" ) {
   echo $country;
}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
if( $country=="United Stats" || $country=="Canada" || $country=="United Kingdom" ) {
   echo $country;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just curious, but is there a reason you prefer the `OR` operator to `||`?

Comment: I assume it was because you initially missed out the OR between the second two countries. That seemed a little harsh, so have a +1 from me.

Comment: @andrewsi - Thanks. And to answer your question, while `||` and `&&` have a higher precedence than `Or` and `And`, I find using `Or` in a case like this more readable.

Comment: You know you've been programming too long when you look at `||` and wonder how someone can find it less readable than `OR` :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid PHP syntax. This one will work:

```
<?php

if( $country == "United Stats" || $country == "Canada"
        || $country == "United Kingdom" ) {
    echo $country;
}

?>
```

By the way, you seem to be new to PHP. You should read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/docs.php) and maybe a book to learn the language.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but telling someone new to PHP to read the docs to learn is not exactly my first choice in learning tools :)

Comment: I'd prefer a book as well, but PHP's docs are quite extensive, and they're faster to get by to get a grasp of the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$country = "Canada";
if( $country=="United Stats" || $country=="Canada" || $country=="United Kingdom" ) {
   echo $country;
}

?>
```